# Where is $f(x) = \log(5x^2-8x-4)+\sqrt{x-1}$ defined?

Tags: functions, inequality

Find the values of $x$ for which function is defined: $f(x) = \log(5x^2-8x-4)+\sqrt{x-1}$.

$ \log(5x^2-8x-4) > 0 \Rightarrow 5x^2-8x-4 > 1 \Rightarrow 5x^2-8x-5 > 0 $

$x = \frac{ 8 \pm \sqrt{160}}{10}$ also $x-1 > 0 \Rightarrow x >1$

Please guide further as answer is $(2, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

This step $5x^2-8x-5>1$ is wrong.

**Hint:**

1. Things in logarithm must be non-negative given the base is positive.
2. Things in square root must be non-negative.

Comment: Is the condition in the first hint sufficient?

Comment: Could the things in the logarithm be equal to zero?

Answer (score 1):

**Some ideas:**

The logarithmic function $\log(x)$ is defined when $x>0$. What you did was $\log(5x^2 -8x - 4) > 0$.

Also, the function $\sqrt{x}$ is defined for $x \geq 0$, which is not what you considered.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two facts:

$5x^2-8x-4 = (5x+2)(x-2)$  When is this product $<0$?

$g(x)=log(x)$ is defined if x>0